# Lots of event hub timeout error in Azure function after migrating to RBAC auth to event hub

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I had an Event hub triggered Azure function which access event hub using connection string in app settings. Recently, I updated the code to access event hub using RBAC auth by configuring fully qualified namespace in app settings like this:

```
"EventHubConnectionSetting__fullyQualifiedNamespace": "my-eh-01.servicebus.windows.net"
```

And the entry of my function is like this:

```
        [FunctionName(FunctionName)]
        public static async Task RunAsync(
            [EventHubTrigger(
                "%EventHubName%",
                Connection = "EventHubConnectionSetting",
                ConsumerGroup = "%ConsumerGroupName%")] EventData[] messages,
            ILogger logger,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
         ...
        }
```

Basically it worked well, but there was always lots of timeout error like this:

```
System.TimeoutException at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpConnectionScope+<OpenAmqpObjectAsync>d__93.MoveNext

Azure.Messaging.EventHubs, Version=5.8.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8

The operation did not complete within the allocated time 00:00:00.1877118 for object out-connection346.
```

I did not see this kind errors before the RBAC auth changes. Is this a known issue?

Below is packages referenced in my function project:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <FunctionsPreservedDependencies Include="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Search.Documents" Version="11.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" Version="2.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs" Version="5.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="6.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver.signed" Version="2.19.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NETStandard.Library" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Polly-Signed" Version="5.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SharpCompress" Version="0.33.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Encodings.Web" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="7.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Is your Azure Function running as an Event Hubs producer or an Event Hubs consumer?

Comment: Can you show more of the Function code?   Azure.Messaging.EventHubs v5.8.1 is not directly referenced by any of the extensions packages, so I'd like to understand the end-to-end scenario better.

Comment: My function is Event hubs consumer. Also updated my question with basic code.

Comment: I'd still like to see the set of packages that you're explicitly referencing as well as the entire stack trace.   What has been provided could indicate that there are network failures and the operation timeout was used up by retries or that token acquisition is taking quite a while.   This may be better investigated as an issue in the Azure SDK repository, as we'll likely need to ask for SDK logs:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues